# Preservation of phase space volume: the extension from "small" times to generic times

Tags: classical-mechanics, phase-space

Having a classical system whose evolution is described by
\begin{equation}
\dot{\phi_t}(x) = f(\phi_t (x))\\
\phi_0 (x) = x
\end{equation}
denoting with $\phi_t (x)$ the evolution for a time t of the point x, one can extend the argument to a set of points defining
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_t = \{s:s=\phi_t (x), x \in\Sigma\}\\
\Sigma_0 = \Sigma
\end{equation}
We are interested in understending how the set of points evolves with particular regard to its volume $|\Sigma_t|$, supposing $f$ is $C^1$ and $\Sigma$ is a regular set.

By definition
\begin{equation}
|\Sigma_t| = \int_{\Sigma_t} dx = \int_{\Sigma} |\frac{\partial \phi_t (x)}{\partial x}| dx = \int_{\Sigma} J_t (x) dx
\end{equation}
where $J_t (x) = |\frac{\partial \phi_t (x)}{\partial x}|$ is the jacobian determinant of the transformation.

So, for "small" times ($t\sim0$), it's easy to prove that if $div{f} = 0$ (the divergence of the vectorial field is equal to zero everywhere) $J_t (x) = 1$ (or, equivalently, $\frac{d J_t (x)}{dt} = 0$) and so the volume of the set is preserved; I understood all this.

The notes of the course go on saying that the theorem is true not only for "small" times but for generic times and to show this and extend the result it's now considered the time $t+\tau$, where $t$ is a generic time and $\tau$ is - again - a "small" time.
So, one can write
\begin{equation}
\phi_{t+\tau} (x) = \phi_{\tau} (x) \circ \phi_{t} (x) = \phi_{\tau} (\phi_{t} (x))
\end{equation}
and, at first order in $\tau$ "small"
\begin{equation}
\phi_{t+\tau} (x) = \phi_{t} (x) + \tau f(\phi_{t} (x)) + o(\tau^2)
\end{equation}
The following equation is also true
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi_{t+\tau} (x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \phi_{t+\tau} (x)}{\partial \phi_{t} (x)} \cdot \frac{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
so that, for $\tau$ "small"
\begin{equation}
|\frac{\partial \phi_{t+\tau} (x)}{\partial x}| = |\frac{\partial \phi_{t+\tau} (x)}{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}| \cdot |\frac{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}{\partial x}|= |\frac{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}{\partial x}| \cdot |\frac{\partial [\phi_{t} (x) + \tau f(\phi_{t} (x))]}{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}|=\\
= |\frac{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}{\partial x}| \cdot |\mathbb{I} + \tau \frac{\partial f(\phi_{t} (x))}{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}| = |\frac{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}{\partial x}| \cdot (1 + \tau \; Tr \frac{\partial f(\phi_{t} (x))}{\partial \phi_{t} (x)})
\end{equation}
where the following *lemma* has been used:
\begin{equation}
|\mathbb{I} + \epsilon A| = Det (\mathbb{I} + \epsilon A) = 1 + \epsilon \; Tr A + o(\epsilon^2) 
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a $n$x$n$ matrix, $Det$ an $Tr$ denote Determinant and Trace of a matrix and $\epsilon$ is a "small" parameter.

In the end, noticing that
\begin{equation}
Tr \frac{\partial f(\phi_{t} (x))}{\partial \phi_{t} (x)} = div f(\phi_{t} (x))
\end{equation}
it is possible to conclude that
\begin{equation}
|\frac{\partial \phi_{t+\tau} (x)}{\partial x}| = |\frac{\partial \phi_{t} (x)}{\partial x}| \cdot (1 + \tau \; div f(\phi_{t} (x)))
\end{equation}
or, in a more compact form
\begin{equation}
J_{t+\tau} (x)= J_{t} (x) \cdot (1 + \tau \; div f(\phi_{t} (x)))
\end{equation}

Up to this point, everything is clear to me while I get lost to the following final step. Infact, from the very last equation the notes conclude that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}J_{t} (x) = J_{t} (x) \; div f(\phi_{t} (x)))
\end{equation}
and - being $t$ a generic (not necessarily "small") time - this was the desired result.

Still, I don't seem to be able to get to this final result. I thought of deriving with respect to $\tau$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\tau}J_{t+\tau} (x)= \frac{d}{d\tau}[J_{t} (x) \cdot (1 + \tau \; div f(\phi_{t} (x)))] = J_{t} (x) \; div f(\phi_{t} (x)))
\end{equation}
but then I don't know how to rigorously show that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\tau}J_{t+\tau} (x) = \frac{d}{dt}J_{t} (x)
\end{equation}

Any help would be welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: The correct identity is $\frac{d}{d\tau} J_{t+\tau}= \frac{d}{dt} J_{t+\tau}$. Indeed,   $\frac{d}{d\tau} J_{t+\tau}(x) = \frac{d(t+\tau)}{d\tau} \frac{d}{d(t+\tau)} J_{t+\tau} =  \frac{d}{d(t+\tau)} J_{t+\tau}$. With the same procedure $\frac{d}{dt} J_{t+\tau}(x) = \frac{d}{d(t+\tau)} J_{t+\tau}$

Comment: However it is not necessary to use that identity. From your 4th formula from the bottom you have $\frac{J_{t+\tau}-J_t}{\tau}= div f(\phi_t(x))$. The limit for $\tau\to 0$ gives rise to your wanted result.

Comment: Your lemma on the determinant function is incorrectly written, after the second $=$, the matrix $1\!\!1$ must be replaced by the number $1$. Perhaps it created some confusion.

Comment: I don't know why I could'n see the limit of that difference quotient. Thank you very much!